# extension=php_openssl.dll not in php.ini

Tags: php, apache, centos

my server is centos 7 , php5.6, apache2.4

```
 php -i | grep -i openssl


 openssl
 OpenSSL support => enabled
 OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
 OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
 Openssl default config => /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
 openssl.cafile => no value => no value
 openssl.capath => no value => no value
 Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

it's enabled Openssl. but my php.ini file is that.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
;
; If you only provide the name of the extension, PHP will look for it in its
; default extension directory.
;
```

i wan't to use extension=php_openssl.dll but i can't find that in php.ini file.

what should i do?

Comment: question is related to dba.stackexchange.com, you can get your help there

Comment: thanks comment. i didn't do your solution but it worked.